# SSIS 2008 best way to run sequential packages

Tags: ssis

At this point,I created several packages that need now to be run sequentially at the end.
How to do that?
Shall I create again a new package and use Execute Package tasks to build my process flow?

Thanks for your tips

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be a good solution.

Alternatively you can use a batch file and call dtexec utility more times.

For instance:

```
dtexec /f "first package path" /Rep EWP
dtexec /f "second package path" /Rep EWP ^ 
       /Set "\Package.Variables[User::VariableName].Value";"CurrentValue"
```

In the second command you can set a package variable. `VariableName`, and `CurrentValue` must be changed.

More information visit [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You run the SSIS packages from SQL Jobs.

You can easily sequence the packages in the Job Steps.